# Может ли свойство объекта ссылаться на другое свойство этого объекта

Tags: javascript

у меня вопрос к знатокам :)
Я пытаюсь сделать динамически генерируемое "дерево решений". Данные которые нужны хранятся в глобальной переменной

```js
const mainObj = {
  second: {
    name: 'second',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },
  
  third: {
    name: 'third',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },
  
  first: {
    name: 'first',
    nextEls: [second, third]
  }
}
```

При инициализации переменной сразу же выхватываю ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: second is not defined`, пробую инициировать через this

```js
const mainObj = {
  second: {
    name: 'second',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },
  
  third: {
    name: 'third',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },
  
  first: {
    name: 'first',
    nextEls: [this.second, this.third]
  }
}
```

переменная инициируется. Но получаю такой объект по итогу

`first: {
    name: 'first',
    nextEls: [undefined, undefined]
 }`

в этом и заключается суть проблемы - можно ли в свойствах ссылаться на свойства? И если да, то как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно хранить *имена* следующих элементов:

```js
const mainObj = {
  second: {
    name: 'second',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },

  third: {
    name: 'third',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },

  first: {
    name: 'first',
    nextEls: ['second', 'third']
  }
}
```

Обращение к самому свойству становится тривиальным.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше ничего сразу же не хардкодить. 
Создайте пустой объект, затем последовательно его заполните:

```
const mainObj = {};

mainObj.second = {
    name: 'second',   
    valueToOutput: "someString"
}

mainObj.third = {
    name: 'third',   
    valueToOutput: "someString"
}

mainObj.first = {
    name: 'first',   
    nextEls: [mainObj.second, mainObj.third]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Суть проблемы - во время создания объекта `mainObj` и его подобъекта `first` (то есть во время выполнения кода, возвращающего значения для свойств этих объектов), этих объектов еще нет.

```js
function createMainObj() {
  var result = {
    second: {
      name: 'second',
      valueToOutput: "someString",
    },

    third: {
      name: 'third',
      valueToOutput: "someString",
    },

    first: {
      name: 'first',
      nextEls: []
    }
  };
  result.first.nextEls.push(result.second);
  result.first.nextEls.push(result.third);
  return result;
}

const mainObj = createMainObj();
console.log(mainObj.first);
```

Comment: Это хороший вариант, когда у тебя мало элементов, но когда их около 1000 - уже проблематичненько определить какой куда запушить и не запутаться. По другому совсем никак?

Comment: @DianaMeissen По-другому - никак. Степень сложности здесь точно такая же, как и в Вашем коде.

Comment: поняла, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать геттеры вместе с `this`, так как `this` актуально только для вызова методов, а не свойств. Но в геттерах этот способ будет иметь доступ только к тому же уровню вложенности (в вашем примере `this` относилось бы к объекту `mainObj.first`, если бы это было возможно):

```js
const mainObj = {
  second: 2,

  third: 3,

  get others() { return [this.second, this.third]; }
}

console.log(mainObj.others);
```

```
[ 2, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Это лучше просто разбить на два действия:

```js
const mainObj = {
  second: {
    name: 'second',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },

  third: {
    name: 'third',
    valueToOutput: "someString",
  },
}

mainObj.first = {
   name: 'first',
   nextEls: [mainObj.second, mainObj.third]
}
```

`this` лучше не использовать, так как во вложенных массивах/объектах контекст просто теряется.
А вообще для таких случаев лучше использовать классы с конструктором:
https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class